# How should a progmode insert the appropriate strings into compilation-error-regexp-alist?

Tags: c#, emacs

I want to modify [csharp-mode.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CSharpMode) so that it includes the appropriate error regex's (regexi?) for the .NET csc.exe compiler.

How should a well-behaved progmode do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A well-behaved Emacs user should probably add the regexp to `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist` and provide the patch to Emacs so it'll get used by all in subsequent releases.

The variable defined in `compile.el` and can be found via

```
M-x find-variable compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist RET
```

I don't think it makes sense for the csharp-mode major mode change the regexp.  If anything, it should set the local value of `compilation-error-regexp-alist` to contain the new symbol you added in the `...-alist-alist` variable.

That said, it could modify the `...-alist-alist` variable by just checking to see if the symbol `c#` (or whatever you add) is a part of the list already, and add it if not.  Note: the `compilation-error-regexp-alist` is defined apriori, so you'll want to double check that variable's contents to ensure it also contains the `c#` symbol.

Comment: Just a follow up; it doesn't work to add things to the two *-alist variables, inside the compilation-mode-hook.  The hook runs *after* the parse, therefore, when you first do `M-x compile`, the necessary regexp will not be on the list.  Subsequent `M-x compile` will have the regexp.  It is appropriate to just call `add-to-list` with the right values, inside the hook for the programming mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did inside [csharp-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CSharpMode):

```
(if (boundp 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist)
    (progn
      (add-to-list
       'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist
       '(ms-csharp 
         "^[ \t]*\\([A-Za-z0-9_][^(]*\\.cs\\)(\\([0-9]+\\)[,]\\([0-9]+\\)) ?: \\(error\\|warning\\) CS[0-9]+:" 1 2 3))
      (add-to-list
       'compilation-error-regexp-alist
       'ms-csharp)))
```